# Generate column of N Null values in SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way to do this? It seems like a pretty simple request that I can't find any support for. I'd just like to generate some arbitrary number of `NULL` values in SQL as a column.

Comment: Use a recursive cte.

Comment: Which SQL dialect? In PostgreSQL, you can probably have some fun with `generate_series()`.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

in postgresql :

```
SELECT NULL FROM generate_series(1,(random()* 100)::int);
```

random n number of null values between 1 and 100